# GCC -finstrument-functions overhead

Tags: gcc, profiling

I'm looking for some performance test results for `-finstrument-functions`.

I'm considering to use it as a profiling tool and therefore I need to know if the overhead isn't too high (so it doesn't mangle the results).

Comment: If you want to make the code faster, [consider this method.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) Instrumenting functions is a popular but not very good way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead is the 2 additional calls to instrumenting functions for each user function call.

It is just 3-5 * 2 asm instructions. Also, The instrumenting functions themselves

```
 __cyg_profile_func_enter 
 __cyg_profile_func_exit
```

will consume time. But if you will to use plain `-finstrument-functions`, the code of cyg_profile functions is yours.

Even if function is inlined, the __cyg_profile* is still called. So, estimate the number of functions calls in target application and multiply to 40-100 cpu ticks of overhead for each call.

You may be interested in sampling profilers, like `oprofile` or linux kernel `perf`.